# Marshaling a Python PIL Image using SWIG

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, swig

I've got a library that takes in a very simple C image structure:

```
// Represents a one-channel 8-bit image
typedef struct simple_image_t {
    uint32 rows;
    uint32 cols;
    uint8 *imgdata;
} simple_image;
```

I didn't create this library, nor this structure, so I can't change it. I'm responsible for wrapping this library for python using SWIG. The Python wrapper needs to be able to take in a PIL Image and convert it into this structure. Here's how I'm doing it right now (using a SWIG `%inline%`):

```
// Allows python to easily create and initialize this structure
simple_image* py_make_simple_image(uint32 width, uint32 height)
{
    simple_image* img = new simple_image();
    img->rows = height;
    img->cols = width;
    img->imgdata = new uint8[height * width];

    return img;
}

// Allows python to set a particular pixel value
void py_set_simple_image(simple_image* img, uint32 pos, uint8 val)
{
    img->imgdata[pos] = val;
}
```

And then on the python wrapper side here's how things look right now:

```
# Make sure it's an 8-bit image
if pil_image.mode != "L":
    pil_image = pil_image.convert("L")

# Create the simple image structure
(width, height) = pil_image.size
img = swig_wrapper.py_make_simple_image(width, height)

try:
    # Copy the image data into the simple image structure
    pos = 0
    for pixel in pil_image.getdata():
        swig_wrapper.py_set_simple_image(img, pos, pixel)
        pos += 1

    # Call some library method that accepts a simple_image*
    return swig_wrapper.some_image_method(img)

finally:
    # Clean up the simple image structure
    swig_wrapper.py_destroy_simple_image(img)
```

Amazingly this works, however as you may have guessed it's **incredibly** slow when working with even moderately large images. I know with SWIG the *proper* way to do things is to use a typemap, however that would mean digging in to the C API of PIL, and I just didn't have time to do that at the moment.

What are my options in terms of speed? Are there quicker ways of marshaling the pixel data from a PIL image to this simple image structure? Has someone already done this and my Google skills are just that bad? Am I just boned and soon will need to learn the internals of PIL?

Thanks.

Comment: The PIL `Image` class contains a few serializing methods - getdata, tostring.  Surely one of these could be coerced into doing what you need.

Comment: @zdav: I'm already using getdata, the problem is that setting my data is too slow using this method. Please see the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIL's `Image.tostring()` returns a string of the exact data you need for `imgdata`.  The typemap I used is fairly simple, but not perfect, which I'll note below.  Here is the sample code I created on Windows that worked for me:

#### sample.h

```
typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef unsigned char uint8;

typedef struct simple_image_t {
    uint32 rows;
    uint32 cols;
    uint8 *imgdata;
} simple_image;

#ifdef SAMPLE_EXPORT
#   define SAMPLE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define SAMPLE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

SAMPLE_API void some_func(const simple_image* si);
```

#### sample.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SAMPLE_EXPORT
#include "sample.h"

void some_func(const simple_image* si)
{
    uint32 i,j;

    printf(
        "rows = %d\n"
        "cols = %d\n",
        si->rows,si->cols);

    /* Dump a simple map of the image data */
    for(i = 0; i < si->rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < si->cols; j++)
        {
            if(si->imgdata[i * si->rows + j] < 0x80)
                printf(" ");
            else
                printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

#### sample.i

```
%module sample

%begin %{
#pragma warning(disable:4100 4127 4706)
%}

%{
#include "sample.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>

%typemap(in) uint8* (char* buffer, Py_ssize_t length) {
    PyString_AsStringAndSize($input,&buffer,&length);
    $1 = (uint8*)buffer;
}

%include "sample.h"
```

#### makefile

```
all: _sample.pyd

sample.dll: sample.c sample.h
    cl /nologo /W4 /LD /MD sample.c

sample_wrap.c: sample.i
    @echo sample.i
    swig -python sample.i

_sample.pyd: sample_wrap.c sample.dll
    cl /nologo /W4 /LD /MD /Fe_sample.pyd sample_wrap.c /Ic:\Python27\include -link /LIBPATH:c:\Python27\libs python27.lib sample.lib
```

#### example.py

```
from PIL import Image
import sample

im = Image.open('sample.gif')
im = im.convert('L')
si = sample.simple_image()
si.rows,si.cols = im.size
s = im.tostring() # Must keep a reference 
si.imgdata = s
sample.some_func(si)
```

With this quick example I haven't determined how the typemap should correctly increment the reference count of the string object.  Note that the above code could crash if the following code were used:

```
si.imgdata = im.tostring()
```

The current typemap's `PyString_AsStringAndSize` returns a direct pointer to the PyString object's buffer, but doesn't increment the reference count for the object.  It can be garbage collected before `some_func` executes (and was for me, crashing Python).  Assigning to `s` keeps a reference to the string and prevents problems.  The typemap should copy the buffer, but you were looking for speed so this hack may be what you want.

Comment: wow, this looks like an awesome answer. My hands are all tied up right now so I can't verify that this works, but this *looks* like the right answer. Give me a few days and I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I could kiss you right now, but I'll just compose myself and award you the 300 points. This drastically reduced the latency. I suspect you're right about the reference count, but I can mess with that on my own time. Thank you very much, this avoids the double copy and speeds are quite tolerable now.

Answer (score 1):

May be you could convert the image to a char array using the `array` module, and then, from swig, memcpy the data to your C array.

```
import array
imagar = array.array('B', pil_image.getdata())
(mem, length) = imagar.buffer_info()
swig_wrapper.py_copy(img, mem, length)
```

being `py_copy` something like:

```
void py_copy(simple_image* img, uint32 mem, uint32 length) {
   memcpy((void*)img->imgdata ,(void*)mem, length );
}
```

Comment: That shaved the time from about 2.5 seconds (average) to about 1.8. I applaud the effort, but there's still a lot of overhead (at least 2 copies that are immediately obvious).

Comment: Instead of using getdata(), which is slow, you could convert the image to a string. I know that the fastest method would be a direct conversion from the PIL object but it requires getting your hands dirty. Profiling information could help identify the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html)?  It allows you to have direct access to c structures, so no need to create a Python equivalent of the struct, and you should also be able to do a memcpy (which would be faster than copying pixel by pixel).

Comment: How would I accomplish the memcpy? I'm fairly certain that `pil_image.getdata()` returns an iterable which wouldn't be useful in a memcpy...

Comment: Good point on memcpy-- it depends on whether the PIL image's pixel buffer is all sequential in memory.  But in case that it is, I googled around, and just found this similar question (and accepted answer).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935616/efficiently-convert-string-or-tuple-to-ctypes-array