# Accessing PIL image data from C extension

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-c-extension

What is the most efficient way in terms of speed to access the pixel data of a PIL image from a C extension?  I only need read-only access to it, if that makes a difference.

Comment: One of [these](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-extending.htm) in reverse may help. But you will still need to profile.

Comment: This answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6539393/235698 might help you.

Answer (score 0):

C-level bindings for PIL are available, but there is very little documentation for them. You will need to consult the source for usage information.

Answer (score 0):

Besides C extension, you can try [numpy](https://numpy.org/). It takes a bit to learn though. To get started, check [Convert RGBA PNG to RGB with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166400/convert-rgba-png-to-rgb-with-pil) , and http://effbot.org/zone/pil-numpy.htm .

In my experience, numpy performance is great if the code is properly written. Processing image data can still be slow using C extension. But numpy uses SIMD instructions such as SSE2, which dramatically improves operation such as histogram elevating or alpha blending.

Comment: I need to pass a PIL image to a third party image compressor written in C, so this really isn't an option for me.